# Magento How to custom "price" font size for product page only

Tags: magento-1.8, css

I'm trying to change font size and color for "Price" on product page only. When I change .price on style.css it would change price format on all pages which is not what I need. I need to change price format on product page only.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a basic CSS question (meaning that the answer applies whether this is Magento or not).

CSS has cascading precedence. A more specific rule will override a general rule. While you might have...

```
.price {
    color: black;
}
```

...you can override this by adding (for a standard Magento theme):

```
.catalog-product-view .price {
    color: red;
    font-size: 20em;
}
```

You will want to test variations (special price, grouped price, etc.) as well.